# androidviewclient touch long press API 17

Tags: androidviewclient

I am unable to do a long press on screen using touch.  My device is API 17 and am using AVC AndroidViewClient-6cd170e65a8869fd9d5915a984342aa3b8937ce7

I have tried drag at same co-ordinate but seems duration and step is ignored for API <= 17.

It would be nice to be able to do a long press by view as well as x, y coordinates.

Regards,

Miten.